# Javascript - : Slider On touch not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am making a custom slider.

All the things works find. But as of now I also want to add ontouch, ontouchmove functionality. I have almost achieve but something is still wrong that's why I am not able to achieve it completely.

Code Snippet

```
function onDragAction (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.type == 'touchmove') {
      caouselPosX2 = caouselPosX1 - e.touches[0].clientX;
      caouselPosX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;
    } else {
      caouselPosX2 = caouselPosX1 - e.clientX;
      caouselPosX1 = e.clientX;
    }
            carouselInneritems.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (carouselInneritems.offsetLeft - caouselPosX2) + 'px)';
}
```

Kindly try the demo on inspect with mobile resolution.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Urhen007/pen/MWwBrVq)

Answer (score 1):

I've had a play around with this and there are two main issues as far as I can see.

1. `onDragAction()` needs to call `e.stopPropagation()` - in the demo you posted it is being called every time a new slide enters underneath the mouse, but you only want it to be called once. This fixes a lot of the glitchiness for me.
2. You need to have some conditional logic to express what direction you want the slider to go in. At the moment it is calculated by subtraction in every case, which from what I've put together from reading your code means it will always go to the left.

Comment: can u provide me a fiddle. For dragAction